# making a button pause and play a sound code error

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode

```
-(IBAction)pause {      
    if ([theAudio isPaused]) {
        [theAudio play];
        else {
            [theAudio pause];
        }
    }
}
```

I have no property for isPaused in .h so maybe that is why. But isPaused turns purple anyways. If i need a property please provide me one as im new to c

Answer (score 2):

The else is inside your if. It should be:

```
if ([theAudio isPaused]) {
    [theAudio play];
}
else {
    [theAudio pause];
}
```